# Why doesn't the scan result contain the complete local name?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using the BluetoothLeScanner to scan for a hardware device.  I have complete control over the advertising data output by this device.  I want the android device to recognise the hardware device based on the "name" which I've given to the device.  This works provided you understand that what Android Studio calls the "name" is (according to the documentation on my Bluetooth device) the beacon advertising data.  But I want the android device to also acquire the complete name which I've put into the scan response data.  No matter what I try, I can't get this data to appear in the scan result anywhere

I've tried probably all of the public methods of ScanResult and ScanRecord

I don't think this helps much, but here's the current code:

```
override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
    super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
    mScan = true
    mString = result?.scanRecord.toString()
}
```

I can't say what's "expected" because I'm trying everything I can think of to make the complete name visible.  The only string that I can get to appear in the result (which it calls mDeviceName) is the shortened form of the name (as I've put it in the scan response data) which is also the beacon advertising data.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific bluetooth device might be advertising its name using device manufacturer specific data. Try debugging your code and inspecting the contents of `result?.scanRecord?.getManufacturerSpecificData()` function.